# Two excel sheets with BIRT 2.6.2

Tags: excel, birt

I am using BIRT 2.6.2.
Into a report I have two cross tabs, and I want that each cross tab to be on a separate excel sheet.

I set to first cross tab the page break property, After = Always, also I set to second cross tab the page break property, Before = Always. But the reports is generated only to one excel sheet.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is natively supported only from version 4.3, using the spudsoft excel emitter. With an older version, unfortunately you have to embed this excel emitter in birt on your own.

Comment: Can you tell me please how can I embed the spudsoft excel emitter in BIRT 2.6.2?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the excel emitter to have this capability. I'm using spudsoft :

https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/wiki/

you should delete the birt default excel emitter and add the spudsoft, then with page break you can have the separated sheets and a lot of useful capability for excel.